# Blur Effect on TableViewCell when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uiimageview

Right now I'm using `LBBlurredImage` to blur an image, but I want to change to **`iOS8`'s `UIVisualEffectView` to blur instead**.

I'm having a hard time implementing, any ideas?

**Implemented with `LBBLurredImage`:**

```
- (void)updateData {
    // Set up Screen
    self.screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    //UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray"];
    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageGlobal];

    // Background Image
    self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.view addSubview:self.backgroundImageView];

    // Background Image Blurred
    self.blurredImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.blurredImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.blurredImageView.alpha = 0.0; // 0.0
    [self.blurredImageView setImageToBlur:background blurRadius:10 completionBlock:nil]; // blurRadius:10
    [self.view addSubview:self.blurredImageView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat height = scrollView.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat position = MAX(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0.0);
    CGFloat percent = MIN(position / height, 1.0);
    self.blurredImageView.alpha = percent;
}
```

**My best shot so far of what I added/changed to the previous code, implemented with `UIVisualEffectView`:**

```
// iOS8
@property (nonatomic) UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
@property (nonatomic) UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;

// iOS8 Blur
self.blurredImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.blurredImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.blurredImageView.alpha = 0.0;
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = self.blurredImageView.bounds;
[self.blurredImageView addSubview:visualEffectView];
[self.view addSubview:self.blurredImageView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I used:

```
// iOS8 Blur
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
self.visualEffectViewGlobal = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
self.visualEffectViewGlobal.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.visualEffectViewGlobal.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:self.visualEffectViewGlobal];
```